# Tomcat Traffic Monitoring

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

What's the best way/tool to measure the amount of traffic has been received/sent from tomcat?

Comment: check out this question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/96612/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-usage-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org)
Its free, easy to deploy and has realtime traffic charts and some other additional benefits.

Comment: about lamdba probe it's dead project, last release was in Nov 2006, that's why I haven't used it, I'm using JavaMelody for monitoring, and it sounds perfect, except it doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I used lambda probe years ago and it was still in my head. Didnt check the project activity before my post, though. Sorry.

Comment: "using JavaMelody for monitoring, and it sounds perfect, except it doesn't have this feature" :
it does have this feature now (global tomcat bytes received/sent, as well as mean bytes per http request)

Answer (score 1):

Most companies where I worked, used only native solutions for this, e.g. for Linux there are quite a few solutions, e.g.: vnStat, iftop, or the more known [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your own `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and then override method `createOutputStream()`, which you can do your own `OutputStream` with counter appened to `write(init i)`, `write(byte[] bytes)` and `write(byte[] bytes, int off, int length)`, It's not easy as it sounds, but this way you can know the length of each response.